# Encoding feature containing both text and string?

Tags: python, encoding, tfidf, one-hot-encoding

I have a feature which has following entries:-

```
| Exterior |
| -------- |
| Vinyl    |
| Wd Sdng  |
| MetalSd  |
| Wd Sdng  |
| HdBoard  |
| BrkFace  |
| Wd Sdng  |
```

and so on.

I am assuming that `Wd Sdng` is a text value and other values are string (but please correct me if I am wrong).

How do I encode this feature since it has both text and string values?

Should I perform a OneHotEncoding or should I perform some kind of NLP encoding (Tfidf etc)??

Comment: Is it possible to clarify the question better with some real data points?

Comment: @jdsuryap edited. Basically my question is, since I have both text (`Wd Sdng`) and string (`vinyl`, `MetalSd` and others) values, how do I encode this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching online, I think I finally got the answer. The observation `Wd Sdng` is not a text type. It is considered a string type (don't know why!) and to encode it, the best thing would be to join both the words, as in `WdSdng` and then apply usual encoding techniques (not text encoding!).

Answer (score 0):

so sorry, but you are confusing peeps with "text" vs "string" ..looking at your examples, they are all "strings" and in this case using any pre trained embedding (glove, word2vec ) wont work very well since most of your strings will come up with 0 while looking up the global embeddings.

One hot will have to be done at character level (meaning at least a 26 dimension vector with 1 non zero) BUT this will be super sparse so, u ll need to take care of that as well ..the best bet is , if you had enough samples, train a local glove embedding (there are scripts available on their git page)

Comment: But isn't `Wd Sdng` a text value as it comprises of 2 strings?

Comment: nope ..basically your datatype definition depends on what you want to do with the data..in this case you want to process all of them together right ? treat everything as string and try any embedding / encoding technique..dont get lost in semantics :) ..good luck

Comment: I want to perform a regression task on this data. So I should treat `Wd Sdng` as a string and perform One hot encoding?